# Given a linear transformation matrix, T, find the equation for the curve that T transforms a circle into.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the linear transformation matrix:

$$T=\pmatrix{2&-3\\1&1}$$

Find the equation for the curve that $T$ transforms a circle with equation $x^2+y^2=6$ into.

What I know:
My basis is going to be $[1,0]^T$ and $[0,1]^T$ because I'm in $\Bbb{R}^2$.
I have my transformation matrix $T$ (usually called $A$?).  $T(x)=Ax$
I have one equation for the circle.
Need to find the equation for the curve. (circle transformed into curve)

I've been working vector/matrix type transformations, so the 'equation' type has me confused.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!!

Comment: did you solve it yet?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook~ Not yet.  I was thinking in terms of the transformations that I've been working with.  ie T(x)=Ax  My A (T given above) is a 2x2 and my x vector is a 3x1.  So it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: why is the $x$ vector $3 \times 1$? I only see $(x,y)$ here. See what you think of my answer.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook~ Check below  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest a less sophisticated approach for this problem. Let us define $T(x,y)=(u,v)$ hence
$$ u = 2x-3y \qquad v = x+y $$
Solve these equations for $x$ and $y$ as functions of $u,v$ and plug-these into $x^2+y^2=6$ and you'll obtain the formula for the image of the circle under the $T$-transformation. Of course, you can understand what happens in terms of deeper theory, but the approach I outline is totally valid for this problem.

Comment: ~  I got (17/25)u^2 + (20/25)uv + (13/25)v^2 = 6  ??

Comment: @Lanae did you get $x = \frac{1}{5}(3v+u)$ and $y = \frac{1}{5}(2v-u)$? These led me to $2u^2+2uv+13v^2=150$ ( multiplied by $25$ due clear out the fractions)

Comment: ~ While I was rewriting my math, I found an error, corrected it and came up with the same result as you.  I see the simplicity in your approach....beautiful!!  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @Lanae it's hard for me to know for sure my approach is what was intended for you at this point in your studies. The advice to look at the SVD later you should come back to a bit later once you have those tools. You can learn where the principle axes for the ellipse reside among other things. A similar question is how to diagonalize a quadratic form, basically there we reveal a special coordinate system where the ellipse formula collapses down to a simple equation with no $xy$-type terms. The principle axes are eigenvectors... read about it.

Comment: ~  SVD is coming up in our lectures.  This is a 5 week summer course in Linear Algebra and its applications in engineering.  Thanks so much for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: it will be an ellipse.  (Do you know about the [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)?)

Comment: ~ I know that it means singular value decomposition.  We have not learned that in this class, yet. I did just read a transformation procedure from ellipse to circle.

Comment: Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0  Therefore, my circle has A=1 C=1 and F=-6  (x^2/a^2)+(y^2/b^2)=1  Therefore, my curve (ellipse) would be A=(1/a^2) C=(1/b^2) and F=-1.

Comment: @Lanae you're analyzing the initial data, but what you should try is to analyze how the equation in $u,v$ is an ellipse. I expect it will be more interesting than the given circle. Maybe there will be a nontrivial $B$ term etc...